# cant insert data in mysql

Tags: mysql, heidisql

So I'm trying to do a trigger in mySQL that looks like:
on table:likes, event:after insert
`IF NEW.`action` = 1 THEN

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO matches
(user_id, user_id_friend) 
(SELECT user_id_from, user_id_to
FROM likes
WHERE user_id_from = NEW.user_id_to AND user_id_to = NEW.user_id_from AND `action` = 1);

IF (SELECT user_id_from, user_id_to
    FROM likes
    WHERE user_id_from = NEW.user_id_to AND user_id_to = NEW.user_id_from
    AND `action` = 1) IS NOT NULL
    THEN

    INSERT IGNORE INTO matches
    (user_id, user_id_friend)
    VALUES
    (NEW.user_id_from, NEW.user_id_to);
END IF;
```

END IF`

the syntax should be right because heidi SQL (the software i'm using) allows me to save it, but when i try to insert something into likes with action = 1, it shows me: MySQL error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try INSERT ON DUPLICATE instead (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: worked that way:
`IF NEW.`action` = 1 THEN   
     
 INSERT IGNORE INTO matches
 (user_id, user_id_friend) 
 (SELECT user_id_from, user_id_to
 FROM likes
 WHERE user_id_from = NEW.user_id_to AND user_id_to = NEW.user_id_from AND `action` = 1);
    
 IF (SELECT user_id_from
  FROM likes
  WHERE user_id_from = NEW.user_id_to AND `action` = 1) IS NOT NULL
  AND 
  (SELECT user_id_to
  FROM likes
  WHERE user_id_to = NEW.user_id_from AND `action` = 1) IS NOT NULL
  THEN 
      
  INSERT IGNORE INTO matches
  (user_id, user_id_friend)
  VALUES
  (NEW.user_id_from, NEW.user_id_to);
 END IF;
END IF`